# How to Trap an exit 0 and echo "check mark"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, exit

I'm trying to figure out something out of my depth, and functionally completely unnecessary. I'm still figuring out Ubuntu as a whole, let alone a scripting language like bash. I've done some C and Java, but it doesn't appear I can script that way.

My plan was to edit `~/.bashrc` to include a C script based on something I found at http://www.linuxcommand.org/wss0150.php , change the values for exit 0 and the message it included, but I figured out pretty quickly that `.bashrc` was particular about its languages.

So, with almost no bash experience to my name, could someone explain how I could trap an exit 0 and echo a check mark, either as a new line or at the end of the input command? This is entirely for my sake as a new Linux user who is unfamiliar with the interface.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask. There may even be an answer there already: what you want to do is add a checkmark (or some arbitrary text) to your command prompt `PS1` if the exit status of the previous command was 0. (Although more typically, people don't change their prompt at all for successful commands, and put something like a X in their prompt if the previous command failed.)

Comment: I have this set up in my .bashrc.  Have a look at https://github.com/xxfelixxx/.dotfiles   Inside the .bashrc file, look for the _prompt_command() function for details on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `PROMPT_COMMAND` in bash to execute something before displaying the next prompt.  If this command includes a change to `PS1` then it will alter your prompt after every command.

I have this setup to produce red `x` marks if the last command had an error, and green `o` marks on success.

Here is my setup:

**Add to your ~/.bashrc**

```
# Do it this way so that long lines don't get messed up
RED_0=$(    tput setaf 1)
GREEN_0=$(  tput setaf 2)
YELLOW_0=$( tput setaf 3)
BLUE_0=$(   tput setaf 4)
PURPLE_0=$( tput setaf 5)
CYAN_0=$(   tput setaf 6)
RESET_0=$(  tput sgr0   )

RED="\[$RED_0\]"
GREEN="\[$GREEN_0\]"
YELLOW="\[$YELLOW_0\]"
BLUE="\[$BLUE_0\]"
PURPLE="\[$PURPLE_0\]"
CYAN="\[$CYAN_0\]"
RESET="\[$RESET_0\]"

CHECK="${GREEN}o"
CROSS="${RED}x"

FANCY_PROMPT="$GREEN\u$YELLOW@\h:$PURPLE\w$BLUE$ $RESET"

_prompt_command() {
    # Show   red x if last command failed
    # Show green o if last command succeeded
    case $? in
        0) PS1="$CHECK $FANCY_PROMPT" ;;
        *) PS1="$CROSS $FANCY_PROMPT" ;;
    esac
    history -a
    true
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="_prompt_command"
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]